# how to check this class has 10 people ? if it does prompt or save the data to database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

i am using vb.net with asp.net

how am i going to check that this class has 10 people already if i continue adding the 11 one it should prompt me that the class is full once i click save button, i know is something like validating but not sure how

i can first add a few student to class 2A and later on continue with adding to another class
however, when i return to add more student into 2A  and save, it should help to check like what i mention above

i have this table call listOfStudent

```
listID    class    student  registerNo
 1         2A       A         123
 2         2A       B         456
 3         2B       C         789
```

i have a aspx web page, i have a drop down list where i select the class

```
txtboxNameOfStudent  txtRegisterNo  
                    addNewRowButton


saveAllStudentDatabutton
```

when enter finish the first row of student data, user can click on the addNewRowButton to add a second row of student data and so on, then after all is done when the user click saveAllStudentDatabutton, it should check whether this class i selected from drop down list has already has 10 student if it does it prompt if it don't it will add in

so how am i going to check?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add a `CustomValidator` to your page: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx), [4guys](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145934/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx).

You'll add something like this to your aspx page:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="classValidator"
        ControlToValidate="{some control name}"
        OnServerValidate="ClassSizeValidate"
        ErrorMessage="This class is full" />
```

Then in your aspx.vb page add something like the following:

```
Sub ClassSizeValidate(sender as Object, args as ServerValidateEventArgs)
    'Code that checks the database if you the class is full

    'if (class is full) then
    '    args.IsValid = False
    'else
    '    args.IsValid = True

End Sub
```

Finally, in your button submit function, at the top you want to make sure that `Page.IsValid = True` before continuing by adding the following line to the top of your function:

```
If Not Page.IsValid then Exit Sub
```